# One Dimensional Java Array From User Input

Tags: java, arrays

coding newbie here. I am sure that my code is inefficient and could use a lot of brushing up.

Now to my question.

I need to take a users input for X number of items in an array, then print that array, grading each item.

The output should look something like, "Student [array position] scored [value of that array position]."

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the number of test scores: ");
    int tests = input.nextInt();
    int [] scores = new int [tests];

    System.out.print("Enter " + tests + " scores: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < tests; i++) {
        scores[i] = input.nextInt();

        int best = scores[0];
        for (int j = 1; j < scores.length; j++) {
            if (scores[j] > best) best = scores[j];

        int gradeA = best - 10;
        int gradeB = best - 20;
        int gradeC = best - 30;
        int gradeD = best - 40;

        if (scores[i] >= gradeA){
            System.out.print("Student " + scores[j] +" score is "
                    + scores[i] + " and grade is A.");
        }
        else if (scores[i] <= gradeB){
            System.out.print("\nStudent " + scores[j] +" score is "
                    + scores[i] + " and grade is B.");
        }
        else if (scores[i] <= gradeC){
            System.out.print("\nStudent " + scores[j] +" score is "
                    + scores[i] + " and grade is C.");
        }
        else if (scores[i] <= gradeD){
            System.out.print("\nStudent " + scores[j] +" score is "
                    + scores[i] + " and grade is D.");
        }
        else{
            System.out.print("\nStudent " + scores[j] +" score is "
                    + scores[i] + " and grade is F.");
        }
        }
    }   
}
```

}

And what I get as output looks crazy:

Enter the number of test scores: 5
Enter 5 scores: 45 78 82 56 74
Student 0 score is 45 and grade is A.Student 0 score is 45 and grade is A.Student 0 score is 45 and grade is A.Student 0 score is 45 and grade is A.Student 78 score is 78 and grade is A.Student 0 score is 78 and grade is A.Student 0 score is 78 and grade is A.Student 0 score is 78 and grade is A.Student 78 score is 82 and grade is A.Student 82 score is 82 and grade is A.Student 0 score is 82 and grade is A.Student 0 score is 82 and grade is A.
Student 78 score is 56 and grade is B.
Student 82 score is 56 and grade is B.
Student 56 score is 56 and grade is B.
Student 0 score is 56 and grade is B.Student 78 score is 74 and grade is A.Student 82 score is 74 and grade is A.Student 56 score is 74 and grade is A.Student 74 score is 74 and grade is A.

Simply put, how do I fix my code to print 5 neat lines in the format ("Student [array position] scored [value of that array position].") stated above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Fix 1 - Loops

**Complete the loop**

```
System.out.print("Enter " + tests + " scores: ");
for (int i = 0; i < tests; i++) {
    scores[i] = input.nextInt();
} // <------------- Finish loop here.
```

**Complete it here too**

```
for (int j = 1; j < scores.length; j++) {
    if (scores[j] > best) best = scores[j];
} // <------------- Finish loop here.
```

**Start it again after calculating grades.**

```
int gradeD = best - 40;

for (int i = 0; i < tests; i++) { // <------------- Started again.
    if (scores[i] >= gradeA){
```

---

### Fix 2 - Index

**Replace**

```
System.out.print("Student " + scores[j] +" score is "
                + scores[i] + " and grade is A.");
```

**with**

```
System.out.println("Student " + i +" score is "
                + scores[i] + " and grade is A.");
```

Happy formatting.
Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, with your help I fixed everything.

Comment: Glad to know it helped. Please mark the answer as accepted if your problem is solved. It saves everyone's time reading through your question even though it's solved. Thanks.

Comment: How do I go about and label it as accepted? Do you mean just edit the main post and say this helped?

Comment: Click on the checked sign below votes of the answer.